# What is the difference between ''Content',''Contest'' and ''Context''?

Tags: word-meaning

I am trying to understand the usage of each word. Is it possible to use any of these words as alternative to the others ?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: @user178049 not yet

Comment: @krebto Any dictionary will clearly define the meanings of these three absolutely different words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Content**

The *content* is what is *in* something. For instance, the *content* of your question is

> I am trying to understand the usage of each word. Is it possible to use any of these words as alternative to the others ?

The *content* of a can can be pickles.

- **Contest**

A *contest* is a competition, where people submit entries, which are then judged, and then have a winner picked.

- **Context**

The *context* is the surrounding information of something. For example, if I provide a quote, say...

> I had an idea that we should serve milk in cups made out of cardboard with holes. It turned out, though, that that was a *really* bad idea. It made a *huge* mess.

So of we take a part of that, like

> That was a *really* bad idea.

Then the *context* would be

> I had an idea that we should serve milk in cups made out of cardboard with holes.

**None of these words can be used interchangeably.**

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, these are three entirely different words with entirely different meanings. Your question has been downvoted because a quick check of any dictionary would have showed you this. This kind of question is best resolved using reference materials.

That said, I think you're possibly getting tripped up on the similarity of *spelling* between these words. Often in English (and possibly other languages) similar spelling can imply some relationship in meaning.

In this case, there is a relationship. All three words use the prefix "con-", which according to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/con-) is a

> word-forming element meaning "together, with," sometimes merely intensive; the form of com- used in Latin before consonants except -b-, -p-, -l-, -m-, or -r-. In native English formations, co- tends to be used where Latin would use con- (e.g. costar).

The same source notes that the origin of "context" is

> 1375-1425; late Middle English < Latin contextus a joining together, scheme, structure, equivalent to contex (ere) to join by weaving ( con- con- + texere to plait, weave) + -tus suffix of v. action; cf. text

While "contest" originated with

> 1595-1605; (v.) < Latin contestāri to call to witness (in a lawsuit), equivalent to con- con- + testārī to testify, derivative of testis witness; (noun) derivative of the v., or < French conteste

In summary, all three words do have a similarity of meaning: they all imply that the concept of "with" something, but they are different words with different meanings, and are not interchangeable.